# How to use globally installed stylelint plugins with stylelint cli?

Tags: stylelint

How can I use globally installed Stylelint plugins in Stylelint CLI?
Can I set the `configBasedir` option as the `node_modules/` path of those plugins?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use globally installed Stylelint plugins in Stylelint CLI?

As of [`stylelint@9.7.0`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/releases/tag/9.7.0), you can reference a globally installed plugin in the same way as you would a locally installed one.

For example:

```
npm i -g stylelint
npm i -g stylelint-selector-no-empty
```

Then in your configuration object e.g. your `.stylelintrc` file:

```
{
    "plugins": ["stylelint-selector-no-empty"],
    "rules": {
        "plugin/stylelint-selector-no-empty": true,
    }
}
```

Finally, run stylelint from the CLI as normal:

```
stylelint your-file.css
```